# Problem for embedding Python in a DLL file called back by a third-party application

Tags: c++, dll, cpython, pybind11

I am trying to build a DLL (using C++) which will be used by a third-party application (TRNEXE.exe). Within the DLL file, I want to embed some Python codes. So I use pybind11 and C/Python API. This works fine with standard modules of Python such as sys, os, traceback, etc. However, when I tried to import a Python module which is found in the site-packages folder, e.g. NumPy, pandas, or other like:
PyRun_SimpleString ("import NumPy") (with C/Python API)
pybind11:: exec ("import NumPy")
or when I import NumPy in an external Python code which is called by a DLL file

The program does not work anymore. It seems the program does not find the packages.

Moreover, I also tried to embed Python code in a C++ console application (it means that I built an executable (not DLL) file from C++ source code which calls some Python codes) and it worked fine with all Python modules.

Does anyone have experience with this kind of problem and have any suggestion for me, please?

PS I set the necessary values in PATH

Comment: Did you also check PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Yes, I also set the PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH but nothing change

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. `sys_path = PySys_GetObject("path");PyList_Append(sys_path, PyUnicode_FromString(py_src_dir));` this works in a console app not in a DLL. Throws a access violation error. I'm trying to `append` one of my dir to `sys.path`. I'm not using `pybind` though.